# How to detect page show event when pressing back in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my jquery mobile app, I want to run a function when the default page shows. This code works

```
    $(document).unbind("pageshow").on("pageshow","#login-page",function(){
        GLOBAL_DATA.user = null;
        alert("reset");
    });
```

But the problem is when I click a button to go to another page, then when I click the back button to go back to the default page, the pageshow function does not trigger. How can I get it to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you unbinding it?

Comment: Ive had problems before where if I didn't unbind it, then I could be stacking the click or other types of functions and functions would be running more than once.

Comment: which version of jquery mobile are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQM 1.4.x try using the pagecontainer widget **[show](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show)** event instead:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
  alert( "The page being shown is: " + ui.toPage.prop("id") );
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zdjj2tc3/1/)**

Comment: @omega, it should work no matter how you navigate. The ui.toPage will be the page you are going to no matter the direction...

Comment: But when I tried it during a forward click, it did not trigger.

Comment: @omega, it works for me in the fiddle I posted. Navigate to page 2 then use the back and forward buttons of the browser. For me it always alerts with the page ID. (I am using chrome on a laptop).